# Differentiate between couple FBRequests in NSMutableDictionary - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, facebook-graph-api, nsdictionary

I'm building a shared manager inside my app what would be responsible for Facebook interaction. 
I need a way for this shared manager to keep a reference to the view controllers who ask for it to do some stuff.
I obviously created some protocol that each such controller can conform to.

I can map in each method call, a FBRequest to a view controller, and when the request returns, look for the appropriate delegate.

I have 2 problems:

1. NSDictionary retain it's values, which I don't want to in this case cause it may cause retain cycles. Is there a way to tell NSMutableDictionary no to retain it's values ?
2. In the case where on of the delegate gets released I need to tell the manager not to forward any callbacks to that delegate, and actually to cancel any live requests.
   Is it the right way to go over the dictionary values and erase the delegate.
   For some reason it just doesn't feel right to go over the values instead of the keys.

P.S - I'm aware that if FBRequest had a userinfo property or a way to work with blocks it may be easier, but I'm curious to know how to solve it in the current situation.

Thanks